# Save data from an Associative Array to the database

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a table with multiple cheque details together with two radio buttons, one for approval and the other for rejecting a specific cheque. 
I would like to update my database with this information when the user submits the form. I have managed to save the data of the radio buttons to an associative array;

```
<td>
   {{ Form::radio('cheque_status['.$cheque->id.']', 'approve' ) }}
</td>
<td>
   {{ Form::radio('cheque_status['.$cheque->id.']', 'reject' ) }}
</td>
```

How do I access this data on my Controller and update the data on multiple rows in the database with this info?
Here is my controller;

```
public function updateApproval(Request $request)
{
    $cheque_status = $request->input('cheque_status');

    foreach( $cheque_status as $key=> $status ) {

           $cheque = Cheque::find( $status );

           if ($status=='approve') {
                $cheque->bca_approval = 1;
            }
            else if ($status=='reject') {
                $cheque->bca_approval = 0;
            }
           $cheque->bca_approval = $status[$key];

           $cheque->save();
        }

    return redirect ('/');
}
```

I am currently getting the error;

> ErrorException (E_WARNING)
>   Creating default object from empty value Creating default object from empty value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try out this solution;

```
public function updateApproval(Request $request)
{
    $cheque_status =  $request->cheque_status;

    foreach( $cheque_status as $key => $status ) {
        if(isset($cheque_status[$key])) {
            $objModel = Cheque::find($key);
            $objModel->bca_approval = $cheque_status[$key];

            if ($status=='approve') {
                $objModel->bca_approval = 1;
            }
            else if ($status=='reject') {
                $objModel->bca_approval = 0;
            }   
            $objModel->save();
        }
    }
    return redirect('/');
}
```